# Can't restart apache2

Tags: apache2

When I wanted to let my apache2 use https, I use this command ：

> sudo a2enmod ssl

and I wanted to restart apache2 I use :

> sudo service apache2 restart

but I got this error ：

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl
-xe" for details.
```

and I use

> systemctl status apache2.service

I got：

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-01-21 09:12:12 CST; 1min 0s ago
  Process: 3861 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 21 09:12:11 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 21 09:37:13 ubuntu apachectl[4439]: apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so)
Jan 21 09:12:12 ubuntu apachectl[3861]: Action 'start' failed.
Jan 21 09:12:12 ubuntu apachectl[3861]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jan 21 09:12:12 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 21 09:12:12 ubuntu systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 21 09:12:12 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

and the line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf is ：

```
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
```

the line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.load is ：

```
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
```

I can't understand what happened, anyone can help me?

Comment: Why is there a custom copy of OpenSSL on your system?

Comment: sorry, I can understand what are you mean?

Comment: Your apache mod_ssl tries to load OpenSSL library from `/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1`.  Package managers don't install libraries in `/usr/local`; it likely appeared there after manual building OpenSSL from sources (someone did `configure`/`make`/`make install` sequence). The question was: why OpenSSL on your system was built from sources.